# .Net Core 2.1 Logging Provider - Should I maintain logger instances?

Tags: logging, .net-core

So I am implementing a custom .Net Core LoggerProvider and I have noticed in some examples that each call to CreateLogger in that provider maintains a reference to each logger in a (Concurrent) dictionary, so the code is something like this:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILogger> _loggers = new 
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ILogger>();

 public ILogger CreateLogger(string name)
 {
     if (_loggers.ContainsKey(name))
     {
         return _loggers[name];
     }

     var newLogger = new CustomLogger();
     _loggers.GetOrAdd(name, newLogger);
     return newLogger;
 }
```

Is there a downside to returning the same instance everytime its requested, essentially treating each instance as a singleton for the lifetime of the app?

Comment: As long as the instances of `ILogger` are thread-safe, there shouldn't be an issue.  This is what I do in my application.

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLoggerProvider.cs as a similar example.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that before and assumed thats where others have gotten their examples from.  I think I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was missing before implementing a similar pattern.

Comment: Should be good, thread safety is key though.

Answer (score 0):

This mechanism is used to supply each logger with seperate `categoryName`. If you do not use category names, you don't need the dict you can simply return a new or singleton logger instance.

It really depends on what you want and the lifetime of each logger. Generally though, you instantiate a logger following a category (e.g. MyApp.SomeApiClient) and you log several times during application lifetime (for example every second). In this case instead of returning a new logger each time, its better to save the logger per category to save you some overhead of recreating it.

An argument can be made that when you don't frequently reuse the logger instances you now  occupy extra memory which you don't need, but i could say all in all this approach is generally the best for 99.99% of use cases. And ofcourse you have overhead from using the concurrent dict.

So in short, you only need the instance to remember the proper category name, and else you can live without it, but you may save on some object allocation / destruction.